# R histogram plotting

Tags: r, histogram

I have a problem with my R double histogram.
I am adding two hist on the same plot, and for some reason the top part of the graph is cut off. I am simply trying to fit all the 'bars' within the plot.
Can anyone please help?
the graph currently looks like this, cut off at the top

```
mut <- subset(data_age, data_mutant =="Mutated")
notmut <- subset(data_age, data_mutant =="not mutated")

set.seed(100)
p1 <- hist(mut, plot=F)                   
p2 <- hist(notmut,plot=F)                     
plot( p1, col=rgb(0,0,1,1/4), xlim=range(c(mut,notmut)))  
plot( p2, col=rgb(1,0,0,1/4), xlim=range(c(mut,notmut)), add=T)
```

[image: the graph currently looks like this, cut off at the top]

Answer (score 4):

Add a `ylim` as well.

```
p1 <- hist(mut, plot=F)                   
p2 <- hist(notmut,plot=F)                     
plot( p1, col=rgb(0,0,1,1/4), xlim=range(c(mut,notmut)), ylim=range(c(p1$counts,p2$counts)))  
plot( p2, col=rgb(1,0,0,1/4), add=T)
```

Comment: ah! great! thank you:)

Comment: Also, you do not need to specify `xlim` for the added plots.

Comment: Hi @Rivendel,  if this has solved your question, please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark.